# Is there a way that I can stop my enemy falling off the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am following a simple code example to do some learning. I have no problem coding up the basic screen, player and enemy. However, when I try to make the enemy move closer it simply falls off the screen.

I have tried slowing the movement, and also setting the speed that it falls to 0 after it is used then resetting it back to the original speed once it is 'safe'. This does not work.

## Space invaders

```
import turtle
import os
```

## setup the screen

```
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")
```

## draw border

```
border_pen=turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()
```

## create the player turtle

```
player=turtle.Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("triangle")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0,-250)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed=15
```

## create the enenmy

```
enemy = turtle.Turtle()
enemy.color("red")
enemy.shape("circle")
enemy.penup()
enemy.speed(0)
enemy.setposition(-200,250)

enemyspeed = 1
enemydropspeed = 40
```

## event handlers for left and right buttons

```
def move_left():
    x=player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    if x < -280:
        x = -280
    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x=player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    if x > 280:
        x = 280
    player.setx(x)
```

## bind to keyboard

```
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left,"Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right,"Right")
```

## main game loop

```
while True:
    # move the enemy
    x = enemy.xcor()
    x += enemyspeed
```

these are the bits that are not working... i think

```
if enemy.xcor() < -280:
    y = enemy.ycor()
    y -= enemydropspeed
    enemyspeed *= -1
    enemy.sety(y)
    
if enemy.xcor() > 280:
    y = enemy.ycor()
    y -= enemydropspeed
    enemyspeed *= -1
    enemy.sety(y)

enemy.setx(x)
```

```
wn.mainloop()
```

When this is run, the enemy will move to the 'right' side of the screen and then just drop off the edge, it should simply move down by 40 and then move along to the left.

Answer (score 1):

I've reworked your game to get it to behave as you describe.  The primary change is I eliminated the `while True:` loop which has no place in an event-driven environment like turtle.  I've replaced it with a timer event:

```
# Space invaders

from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SIZE = 600
BORDER_WIDTH = 3
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

PLAYER_SPEED = 15
ENEMY_DROP_SPEED = CURSOR_SIZE * 2

# event handlers for left and right buttons

def move_left():
    x = player.xcor() - PLAYER_SPEED

    if x < CURSOR_SIZE/2 - SIZE/2:
        x = CURSOR_SIZE/2 - SIZE/2

    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor() + PLAYER_SPEED

    if x > SIZE/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2:
        x = SIZE/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2

    player.setx(x)

# main game loop

def move_everything():
    global enemyspeed

    # move the enemy
    x, y = enemy.position()

    x += enemyspeed

    if not CURSOR_SIZE/2 - SIZE/2 <= x <= SIZE/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2:
        y -= ENEMY_DROP_SPEED
        x -= enemyspeed

        enemyspeed *= -1

    enemy.setposition(x, y)

    screen.ontimer(move_everything, 50)

enemyspeed = 5

# setup the screen

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Space Invaders")

# draw border

border = Turtle(visible=False)
border.speed('fastest')
border.color("white")
border.pensize(BORDER_WIDTH)

border.penup()
border.setposition(-SIZE/2 - BORDER_WIDTH, -SIZE/2 - BORDER_WIDTH)
border.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    border.forward(SIZE + BORDER_WIDTH*2)
    border.left(90)

# create the player turtle

player = Turtle("triangle")
player.color("blue")
player.penup()
player.speed('fastest')
player.sety(CURSOR_SIZE/2 - SIZE/2)
player.setheading(90)

# create the enenmy

enemy = Turtle("circle")
enemy.color("red")
enemy.speed('fastest')
enemy.penup()
enemy.setposition(CURSOR_SIZE/2 - SIZE/2, SIZE/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2)

# bind to keyboard

screen.onkey(move_left, "Left")
screen.onkey(move_right, "Right")
screen.listen()

move_everything()

screen.mainloop()
```

As far as your original code, when it reached the edge, instead of coming back over the edge, it just seemed to dither.  The x coordinate approaching the edge:

```
277
278
279
280
281
282
281
282
281
282
```

My belief is immediately backing out the most recent move once you've gone over should help, which I've done above.